# Morocco - Covid-19 Vaccination Requirement

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, covid-19, morocco

Does anybody know (for certain) what the sentence on the [Moroccan National Tourist Office website](https://www.visitmorocco.com/en/travel-info/covid-19-travel-safely-to-morocco) means:

> A valid vaccine passport means receipt of three doses or, failing
> that, two doses with a delay in the administration of the second dose
> not exceeding 4 months.

Does this mean that in the case of an un-boosted traveler, the second dose must have been received within 4 months of travel to Morocco, or no more than 4 months after the first dose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wording is tricky! However, they mean that the second dose was taken no more than 4 months before traveling to Morocco.

I have tracked down the [official information](https://www.sante.gov.ma/Documents/2022/05/Protocle-Sanitaire_Voyages_Mai%202022%20(Ar).pdf) from the ministry of health in Morocco and it says that (in Arabic).